# reset counter when using \LTRfootnote from bidi package

Tags: xetex, footnotes, xepersian

I'm using `xepersian` package for my Persian job, and I would like the footnote counter to automatically restart from '1' for each page of my document when I using `\LTRfootnote` command, but `footmisc` package not work with this command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best possible choice is to use `zref-perpage` package from [`zref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zref) bundle. It provides a `\zmakeperpage[<reset>]{<counter>}` command to force a counter reset with each page. Therefore adding

```
\zmakeperpage{footnote}
```

in your preamble will do the job. A mwe is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\zmakeperpage{footnote} 
\begin{document}
سلام~\footnote{یک پانویس}. همچنین\LTRfootnote{A footnote}.\par
سلام~\footnote{یک پانویس}. همچنین\LTRfootnote{A footnote}.
\newpage
سلام~\footnote{یک پانویس}. همچنین\LTRfootnote{A footnote}.\par
سلام~\footnote{یک پانویس}. همچنین\LTRfootnote{A footnote}.

\end{document}
```

Another example without persian scripts, but still with presence of [`XePersian`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xepersian) package is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\zmakeperpage{footnote} 
\begin{document}
\begin{latin}
Hello\footnote{Hi} world\LTRfootnote{Everyone!}!\par
Hello\footnote{Hi} world\LTRfootnote{Everyone!}!
\newpage
Hello\footnote{Hi} world\LTRfootnote{Everyone!}!\par
Hello\footnote{Hi} world\LTRfootnote{Everyone!}!
\end{latin}
\end{document}
```

BTW: The reason for `footmisc` not to works is that [`xepersian`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xepersian) depends on [`bidi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bidi) package (by the same author) for bidirectional typesetting; and `bidi` has extensive features for footnotes and it might conflict with some macros of `footmisc`.

You can also use `perpage` package, but it requires two runs of `xelatex`.