# Reset footnote for paragraphs spread in two pages

Tags: footnotes

To reset footnote numbering on each page I use

```
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
```

But if a paragraph including a footnote spread in two pages, the numbering is not reset on the next page

```
-----footnote{A}----
--------------------
------
--------------------
--------------------  <- End of a page 1
1. A

-------------------- <- the rest of previous paragraph
--------- footnote{B}
-------
-------------footnote{C}
------------------------
2. B
1. C
```

I use `xepersion` and `xelatex` compiler for a document in Persian. Is this problem exist for English too or its a bug in my settings?

You can see this behavior in the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=5.1cm, bottom=4.6cm, left=3.8cm, right=3.8cm}
%\geometry{top=5.1cm, bottom=4.6cm, left=5.8cm, right=5.8cm}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}


\usepackage{xepersian}

\setstretch{1.54}
%\linespread{1.8}

\begin{document}
‎\blindtext\LTRfootnote{paragraph}‎

\blindtext[2]\LTRfootnote{paragraph}‎

\blindtext\LTRfootnote{paragraph}‎      
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, footmisc requires two passes. Does the problem go away if you run `xelatex` again without changing the document?

Comment: @Gilles it seems the bug is from `LTRfootnote`

Comment: @Gilles I added my answer which resolved the problem, however I remember it didn't work for `zref` but this time I compiled it with `zref` twice, it worked, but after then it doen't need twice compile to work!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117116/reset-counter-when-using-ltrfootnote-from-bidi-package), I should use `zref` package as follows

```
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\zmakeperpage{footnote}
```